# pywin32 programming error on Win7 with shell.SHGetDesktopFolder,desktop.BindToObject,desktop.GetDisplayNameOf

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, win32com

When running the following code on WinXP , all is fine ,

```
from win32com.shell import shell

def launch_file_explorer(path, files):

    folder_pidl = shell.SHILCreateFromPath(path,0)[0]
    desktop = shell.SHGetDesktopFolder()
    shell_folder = desktop.BindToObject(folder_pidl, None,shell.IID_IShellFolder)
    name_to_item_mapping = dict([(desktop.GetDisplayNameOf(item, 0), item) for item in shell_folder])
    to_show = []
    for file in files:
        if file not in name_to_item_mapping:
            raise Exception('File: "{}" not found in "{}"'.format(file, path))
        to_show.append(name_to_item_mapping[file])
    shell.SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(folder_pidl, to_show, 0)
import os


p=r'E:\aa'
print(os.listdir(p))
launch_file_explorer(p, os.listdir(p))
```

however ,when tested on Win7,I got the following error

```
['b1', 'b2', 't.txt']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\g.py", line 21, in <module>
    launch_file_explorer(p, os.listdir(p))
  File "D:\g.py", line 13, in launch_file_explorer
    raise Exception('File: "{}" not found in "{}"'.format(file, path))
Exception: File: "t.txt" not found in "E:\aa"
```

I nearly have no experience on pywin32 programming ,the above code is googled,anyone can help me fix this error ?thanks in advance !

Comment: thanks, I found out the reason： this question has no relationship with Win7 
or WinXP,but related to the users' system setting . 
GetDisplayNameOf() only gives the DISPLAY  name ,so the filename with or without extension acording to whether the user want to view files in the explorer with extension .
my settings is that filename with extension on WinXP but not on Win7,while os.listdir() returns filenames with extension on both of them ,this caused my problem here .
so anyone know how to fix my problem ? I mainly want to use shell.SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems() here.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.python/Zaz2nIiEUBE